# Best way to ‘face’ this object

Tags: faces

I have this object, what is the best way to get the faces created?

I hope that makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Fill is the term often used to refer to filling edges with faces.

Comment: Yeah, i am struggling to fill in a good way though. The circles are cut-outs. So there is a rectangle with 2 circles in it that need to be 'filled'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with the Boolean Modifier.

First select your cutouts in edit mode and press <kbd>P</kbd>.
Choose Separate by Selection. Then Extrude them trough your contour object.
[image]

Then Subdivide the edges on both sides of your cutout objects and subdivide then by 2.
(this is optional)
[image]

Select the new vertices, press <kbd>G</kbd> twice and move them next to your cutout objects. (also optional)
[image]

Then <kbd>Alt</kbd> select an edge of your contour object and press <kbd>F</kbd> (better to press F then to go by the menu; picture a bit misleading)
[image]

Now select your contour object (which is now a plane) and add a Boolean Modifier.
Properties window > Modifier Properties tab > Add Modifier. Then choose Boolean.
Then as Object choose your cut out object and click Apply. If you have multiple separate cutout objects repeat it for every one of them.
[image]

Then hide or delete your cutout objects. And you're done.
[image]

**EDIT:**

Don't want to use boolean?

Make sure all geometry is part of a single object.

In Edit Mode, use <kbd>F</kbd> to create edges between vertices, around your cutout geometry.

Use Subdivide to have the surrounding geometry have an equal number of vertices as the cutout geometry.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (or click the Edge button), and select Bridge Edge Loops.

[image]

If not careful, created edges between vertices can cross the cutout geometry area if they happen to be aligned that way.
[image]

Also an unequal amount of vertices can cause problems.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was trying not to use Boolean, but the above worked perfectly.  Thanks again